# MAU data needed for SNMP agent

Tags: linux, embedded, snmp

I am trying to write an `snmp agent` for `RFC 4836`, Definitions of Managed Objects for `IEEE 802.3 Medium Attachment Units (MAUs)`, to run on an embedded Linux system (Linux server 2.6.35.12+).  I've used `mib2c` to set up my frameworks, but am stalled on finding where to get the data to fill in. I am not sure where I should be looking: if the `MAU` is part of the `eth device` or `a separate interface`, if I should be looking somewhere in the `/sys` or `/proc` `fs`, or if I need to access the device registers directly (or both?).

---

I know there is a lot of different data needed, and am not asking for a roadmap with everything, but at this point I am hung up and not sure where I should be concentrating my efforts - driver code?

Sorry if this seems a dumb question, but I have been looking online and in StackOverflow without finding what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the information I needed is available from mii-tool. Despite what you may see on the web, this is not obsolete (it may have been a few years ago but it seems to have been updates). Or, you can access the device registers directly using ioctl calls to SIOCGMIIREG, to avoid having to parse command output.